# Config library which allows to define scopes

Tags: java, scala, config

I'm looking for a simple enough and decent java/scala library which allow to define the scopes like the following:

```
scope1 {
  scope2 {
    ke1 = value1
  }
}
```

I could use `akka` config, but unfortunately it only works within (or involving) an actor system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) - it supports exactly what you described.

Adapted from the [examples](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/examples/scala/complex-app/src/main/resources/complex2.conf):

```
complex-app {
    something = "..."

    simple-lib {
        foo = "..."
        whatever = "..."
    }
}
```

Comment: does it involve akka somehow?

Comment: Quote: implemented in plain Java with no dependencies

Comment: actually, java and scala.

Comment: ... and by the way, Akka (as most Scala projects) uses this libarary for configuration

Comment: and if a project has a few modules in it, one of the modules has the config file (app.config), will other modules be able to read this config via typesafe config?